# How to format amount in office excel add ins

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I am developing excel add-ins using office.js, javascript and react. Wants to show different decimal number formats in columns.
consider blow values receiving in response to show it on excel columns:

```
23.233456789 -> 23.23
24.123456 -> 24.12
26.98576362 -> 26.98
```

So on cell column values should show like 23.23, 24.12, 26.98 and on selecting that specific cell it should show whole amount like for 23.23 -> 23.233456789 etc.
Is it possible to do such formatting using office.js? please help to find out the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Range.numberFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#numberFormat) property to do this. Here's an example.

```
async function setNumberFormat() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");

    const formats = [["0.00", "0.00"], ["0.00", "0.00"], ["0.00", "0.00"]];

    const range = sheet.getRange("D3:E5");
    range.numberFormat = formats;
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

When a cell is selected, the full actual value appears in the Formula Bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about office.js, but you can do so with a simple rounding function. This will round the number to at most two decimal places.

```js
function roundNumber(num){
 return Math.round(num * 100) / 100
}
```

Comment: Yes, round is the option but on selecting cell it should show whole digits. this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to a table column, this is how I do it:

```
table.columns.getItem(columnName).getRange().numberFormat = [["#,##0.00"]];
```

Though it's basically the same for anything that you can `getRange()` from.